# Passing Data into Angular App from External Application

Tags: angular, http, hybrid

I have a windows form application that has a browser which loads my angular site.

I have an object model class (series of fields with data) that I want to get into my angular application when it loads up in my browser.

I also am using routes. So, mysite.com\mainpage is one route and mysite.com\customizemainpage is another.

I know I can do it with route parameters. EG: mysite.com\mainpage...serialized encoded data from win forms...\

However, this is not that secure... compare to posting data.

I know this sounds weird since I GET the web-site... however, while doing this I want to POST data into angular. Such, that inside my angular application I can turn it into a typescript objects (model).

Is there anyway to do this, other than URL PARAMS?

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: You can post the data to your angular app URL. Now the server which serves your angular app can parse the post data and put that data in some form and attach that form in index.html. After attaching that form to index.html. I recently experienced similar requirements and I solved it like that. So your windows form app will post the data to the angular app URL and then your server (in my case it was ASP.NET core server) will parse the post data and put the form in index.html. Later the posted URL will read the form in angular app and do its job.

Comment: Thanks user2216584..... Right now I am using Visuals Studio Code.... and 'ng serve' to host it while I develop the site. With this, do you know how I can access the posted data?

I have been searching, but stuff about sending data into a component keeps coming up (which I know how to do). I can inject the Http module and see if there is data from there I can view.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ng serve` only works for GET calls, and to set up POST calls using `ng serve` you need to write a custom webpack configuration which could be tricky as well. I will suggest you to deploy your site to some server like IIS using ASP.NET Core (or whatever your server is) and write the server code to parse the POST data and attach that data to index.html before serving that URL request.

Comment: Oh, ok wow, thank you. This definitely clears a lot of my struggles up. Thank-You